# amcharts - how to set lat/lon in mappolygon?

Tags: javascript, maps, amcharts

Basically, I just want to plot a circle, at a user defined lat/lon with a radius of X km.

So I realize looking through documentation, I can't change the lat/lons of the mappolygons that are already loaded through the geodata, but I guess I'm not quite sure how to create a new map polygon with a specified lat/lon or if I can even do that!

My code is set up so that everytime the user clicks somewhere a marker is plotted or replotted accordingly, the location of the marker is where I would like to plot the center of the circle. I get that using the getCircle function I need to do the whole km2deg for the third variable, but I'm more concerned with the location right now. Any help would be great!

https://codepen.io/kbreezy/pen/wLRrPq

below is my onclick method of the code.

```
chart.seriesContainer.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  var lp = $("#chartdiv").data("point");
  var coords = chart.svgPointToGeo(ev.svgPoint);

  if (lp) {
      lp.latitude = coords.latitude;
      lp.longitude = coords.longitude;
  } else {
    var marker = imageSeries.mapImages.create();
    marker.latitude = coords.latitude;
    marker.longitude = coords.longitude;
  }
  $("#chartdiv").data("point", marker);


  var circleSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries())
    var circleTemplate = circleSeries.mapPolygons.template;
    circleTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#bf7569");
    circleTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;
    circleTemplate.fillOpacity = 0.75;


  var polygon = circleSeries.mapPolygons.create();
  var mapPolygon = polygonSeries.getPolygonById("DE");
  mapPolygon.setPropertyValue('latitude', coords.latitude);
  mapPolygon.setPropertyValue('longitude', coords.longitude);
  polygon.latitude = coords.latitude;
  polygon.longitude = coords.longitude;
  polygon.multiPolygon = am4maps.getCircle(mapPolygon.visualLongitude, mapPolygon.visualLatitude, 5);


//polygon.multiPolygon = am4maps.getCircle(coords.latitude, coords.longitude, 5);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

MapPolygon does not have some latitude/longitude where you could "move" it. It's multipolygon must contain coordinates of the area you want to show. So when you pass longitude/latitude to the getCircle method, it returns multiPolygon around that point.

I modified your pen where to show the concept: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/ydrLZw

```
polygon.multiPolygon = am4maps.getCircle(coords.longitude, coords.latitude, 5);
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH YOURE A BABE. honestly a little upset on simple that was cause I swear I tried that but oh well haha thank you a bunch.